# How to keep page state during all time while app runs? (WP8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

For example, I have 3 pages in my app. It has the following navigation map:

MainPage >> InfoPage >> SettingsPage.

So, if I go to SettingsPage from InfoPage and then use Back button, InfoPage keeps its state.

But if I go from InfoPage to MainPage using Back button and the go again to InfoPage, InfoPage loses its state, and starts loading again.

How can I keep InfoPage state during all the time while app runs? I need to initialize it only once.

Comment: why dont You disable Back button when You are in Infopage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to create a cache for that page. Then on load retrieve the cache from isolated storage.

Your flow would look something like this

```
> >>OnNavigatedToMethod_AnyPage
> -->Check if cache exists in isolated storage
> --->If it does get the cache and load the values into the page
> ---> if it doesnt exist create a new one and save default values
> 
> >>OnNavigatedFromMethod_AnyPage
> -->Load values into cache object
> --->Save cache object to isolated storage
```

So how do we actually do this?

Well first thing is [download the isolated storage dll I wrote called EZ_Iso](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2)

Next step is implement it.

First create your page cache object

```
[DataContractAttribute]//This tells the EZ_Iso dll that this object is serializable 
public PageOneCache{

    [DataMember] //This tells the serializer to serialize this member
    public bool flag1 {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public List<int> ages {get;set;}

    public int boxes {get; set;} // This member doesn't have the [DataMember] so it wont get saved
}
```

Okay now that we have our cache object lets save it

```
PageOneCache pageOneCache = new PageOneCache(){ flag1 = true, ages = new List<int>(){1,3,4}, boxes = 2};

if(EZ_iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.FileExists("pageOneCache")
   Ez_iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.OverwriteFile("pageOneCache",pageOneCache);
else
   Ez_iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.SaveFile("pageOneCache",pageOneCache);
```

Once you've done that your cache is saved to the phone's isolated storage. It will be safe regardless if the app is running or not. The phone can shut completely down and it will be fine.

Now for retrieving

```
PageOneCache pageOneCache = (PageOneCache)EZ_iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.GetFile("pageOneCache",typeof(PageOneCache));
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you! One more question. How to add this dll to project and get access to it in project?

Comment: I tried to use "Add Reference...", but Visual Studio tells that it is uncompatible.

Comment: Are you sure you're doing a Windows Phone 8 project?

Comment: Of cource. BTW, dll has version 3.0 on your webpage, but VS show version 1.0.0.0

Comment: I incorporate this dll into every single one of my apps. It has been also incorporated into a number of other apps written by other people. I am 100% sure it works with Windows Phone 8. I would google how to add a reference if there is still confusion.

Comment: Just installed English lang pack on Visual Studio. Now I can exactly say, what error is. So, when I try to add reference, VisualStudio says: "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project". Maybe I try to add DLL incorrectly? So, how do you add DLLs?

Comment: When you downloaded the DLL did you right click on it, select properties and click unblock?

Comment: No, I didn't. Should I do that?